# Tools for practicing problem solving and expression of algorithms

Tags: algorithms, education

I'm involved in a university course which is a crash course in the basics of problem solving and common concepts in computer science. The course contains a number of practical assignments and ends with a group project (~30 hours) in which at least two students solve a problem given to them. Lately we have focused on assigning problems to be solved by use of some computer program and/or device. Examples include visualizing algorithms in a virtual world by use of Alice and Scratch, as well as programming pre constructed Lego Mindstorms robots to perform specific tasks. We think those kinds of environments are suitable because of the low pre-requisites needed and because of the quick feedback that the students are given. As a bonus, the presentations tend to not be boring.

We are currently searching for additional tools to use in the course, which is why I ask you users of Stack Exchange Computer Science this:

What kinds of tools have you come across that could be used to practice problem solving and expression of algorithms? Feedback does not have to be visual -- we are investigating sound/song generation as a possible assignment. What is important is that basically any pair of students should be able to solve our assignments (with guidance if needed) in ~30 hours. That is, the students should not need any pre existing knowledge other than possibly basic mathematics. Whatever tool is required must be available for free.

Comment: I'm not sure this a good question, as it seems quite subjective. Tools I've come across that worked for me perhaps didn't work for somebody else.

Comment: Pens and paper. *Maybe* a text terminal with a compiler.

Comment: Do you know https://projecteuler.net

Answer (score 0):

Problem solving is best done (in my opinion) on pencil and paper. However, some other useful tools for helping solving problems is Wolfram|Alpha. If you need to, Python is a fairly good scripting language for solving problems. Of course, this all depends on what kind of problem you are working on (for example, a geometry problem would be very difficult to solve using Python).